# Epsilon-Delta proof of the limit of an arbitrary line

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Consider the line $f(x)=mx+b$, where $m\neq 0$.  I have to use the epsilon-delta definition to show that 
$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=mc+b$$

So given $\varepsilon >0$
$$|f(x)-L|=|(mx+b)-(mc-b)|=|mx-mc|=|m(x-c)|=|m||x-c|<\varepsilon$$
Thus $|x-c|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|m|}$, and then I can choose $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{|m|}$.

To finish, $0<|x-c|<\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{|m|}$, then
$$0<|m||x-c|=|(mx+b)-(mc+b)|=|f(x)-L|<|m|\delta<\varepsilon$$.

Is this sufficient?

Comment: at a quick glance this looks ok but I'm not completely sure

Comment: It's good, but I would type "if $0<|x-c|<\delta$..."

Comment: Yup, that's correct.

Comment: because the definition is an "if then", right?

Comment: By the way, @GitGud, thanks for the help earlier today with the Lagrange problem.  I realized I haven't utilized my calc skills in a while and am brushing up on some stuff.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Yes, because it is a conditional statement. You're welcome.